# How do I calculate the SIZE of stored procedures in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I was asked for a comprehensive breakdown on space used within a specific database. 
I know I can use *sys.dm_db_partition_stats* in SQL Server 2005 to figure out how much space each *table* in a database is using, but is there any way to determine the individual and total size of the *stored procedures* in a database? (Short of opening each one and counting the characters, of course.)

Total space used by stored procs is not likely to be significant (compared to actual *data*), but with hundreds of them, it could add up.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
;WITH ROUTINES AS (
    -- CANNOT use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES because of 4000 character limit
    SELECT o.type_desc AS ROUTINE_TYPE
            ,o.[name] AS ROUTINE_NAME
            ,m.definition AS ROUTINE_DEFINITION
    FROM sys.sql_modules AS m
    INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
        ON m.object_id = o.object_id
)
SELECT SUM(LEN(ROUTINE_DEFINITION))
FROM ROUTINES
```

Comment: Nice!!

Bonus points for also giving me the size of Triggers, Views, and Scalar functions!

Answer (score 4):

A slightly better way than counting the characters, is to use information schema.routines.  You could sum the length of each Routine Definition as (Note each routine definition will max out at 4,000 characters, see below for a method that doesn't have this restriction):

```
select Sum(Len(Routine_Definition)) from information_schema.routines 
where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

Or you could return the length of each sp

```
select Len(Routine_Definition), * from information_schema.routines 
where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

It's unlikely that the length of your stored procedures is the problem.  Usually running out of space with a database is due to things like not backing up the log file (and then shrinking it using dbcc shrinkfile or dbcc shrinkdatabase).

In Sql 2000, here is a routine that would provide the length without the 4000 character limit of above:

```
DECLARE @Name VarChar(250)
DECLARE RoutineCursor CURSOR FOR
   select Routine_Name from information_schema.routines where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'

DECLARE @Results TABLE
   (   SpName   VarChar(250),
       SpLength   Int
   )

CREATE TABLE ##SpText
   (   SpText   VarChar(8000)   )

OPEN RoutineCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM RoutineCursor INTO @Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO ##SpText   (SpText)   EXEC sp_helptext @Name

      INSERT INTO @Results (SpName, SpLength) (SELECT @Name, Sum(Len(SpText)) FROM ##SpText)
      TRUNCATE TABLE ##SpText

      FETCH NEXT FROM RoutineCursor INTO @Name
   END

CLOSE RoutineCursor
DEALLOCATE RoutineCursor
DROP TABLE ##SpText

SELECT SpName, SpLength FROM @Results ORDER BY SpLength DESC
SELECT Sum(SpLength) FROM @Results
```

Comment: That maxes out at 4000 characters.  I'm working on a different approach similar to another routine we use.

Comment: but yeah - if you're running out of room because of sprocs, You're Doing It Wrong!

Answer (score 4):

Need to use DATALENGTH rather than LEN to get the number of bytes rather than the number of characters because the definition column of the sys.sql_modules catalogue view is NVARCHAR(MAX) i.e. Unicode

```
SELECT Type,
   SUM(Chars)  SizeChars,
   SUM(Bytes)  SizeBytes,
   SUM(Bytes) / 1024. SizeKB,
   CAST(SUM(Bytes) / 1024 AS VARCHAR) + '.' + CAST(SUM(Bytes) % 1024 AS VARCHAR) SizeKBRemBytes
FROM
(
SELECT o.type_desc Type, 
       LEN(sm.definition) Chars,
       DATALENGTH(sm.definition) Bytes
    FROM sys.sql_modules sm
    JOIN sys.objects o ON sm.object_id = o.object_id
) x
GROUP BY Type
ORDER BY Type
```

Answer (score 4):

Improve Cade Roux answer:

```
/*
<documentation>
  <summary>Count size in bytes veiws, triggers, procedures and function in database.</summary>
  <returns>1 data set: RoutinType, SUM LENGTH of objects, SUM DATALENGTH.</returns>
  <issues>No</issues>
  <author>Cade Roux</author>
  <created>2008-10-20</created>
  <modified>2019-06-26 by Konstantin Taranov</modified>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <sourceLink>https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit/blob/master/Scripts/Objects_Size_In_Database.sql</sourceLink>
  <originalLink>https://stackoverflow.com/a/219740/2298061</originalLink>
</documentation>
*/

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

WITH CTE_Routine AS (
    /* Can not use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES because of 4000 character limit */
    SELECT o.type_desc     AS RoutineType
         , o.[name]        AS RoutineName
         , m.[definition]  AS RoutineDefinition
    FROM   sys.sql_modules AS m 
    INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
)
SELECT RoutineType
     , SUM(LEN(RoutineDefinition))            AS RoutineLen
     /* DATALENGTH for counting trailing space in the end of objects definitions */
     , SUM(DATALENGTH(RoutineDefinition)) / 2 AS RoutineDatalength
FROM   CTE_Routine
GROUP BY RoutineType;
```

Comment: This answer is better in the sense that the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINE is limited to the first 4000 characters - it won't show the whole length.

Comment: WITH sps AS (
    SELECT o.type_desc     AS RoutineType
   , SCHEMA_NAME( o.schema_id ) AS RoutineSchema
         , o.[name]        AS RoutineName
         , m.[definition]  AS RoutineDefinition
    FROM   sys.sql_modules AS m 
    INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
)
SELECT s.RoutineSchema 
 , s.RoutineName
     , SUM(LEN(RoutineDefinition))            AS RoutineLen
FROM   sps s
GROUP BY s.RoutineSchema
 , s.RoutineName
ORDER BY s.RoutineSchema
 , s.RoutineName

Answer (score 2):

Dave_H's solution hits a limit of 4,000 character in the information_schema.routines table

Try this, first you generate the a table with the full text of the sprocs, then sum the character lengths.

```
--create a temp table to hold the data
create table ##sptext (sptext varchar(1000))
go

--generate the code to insert the full text of your sprocs
select 'insert into ##sptext (sptext) exec sp_helptext '''+specific_name+''';'
from information_schema.routines 
where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
go

/*Copy the output back to your query analyzer and run it*/

--now sum the results    
select sum(len(sptext))
from ##sptext
```