# Count Stored Procedures in Database?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

How can i count the number of stored procedures in my database and is it a bad practice to have too many stored procedures?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Select count(*) from sysobjects where xtype = 'P'
```

Comment: Using "sysobjects" directly is frowned upon - you're better off using either the "sys." or INFORMATION_SCHEMA catalog views.

Comment: I dunno, extra keypresses for `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` or `sys` make me frown, and therefore are frowned upon.  What's the big deal with it @marc_s ?

Answer (score 6):

```
Select count(1) from information_schema.routines
where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

Answer (score 2):

you may want to exclude system stored procedures from your count

One way would be to call:

```
select count(*) from sysobjects 
    where xtype = 'P'
    and category = 0
    and left(name,2) <> 'sp'
```

That is assuming that you do not prefix your procedures with sp

Comment: System stored procedures are generally prefixed with 'sp_', though I've seen production systems where 'sp_' is the prefix used for the user-defined procs :-(

Answer (score 1):

You need as many as your application requires.  Keeping procedures small and simple is a good thing.

If you're using sql 2005, a visual way to see your proc count is to navigate in SSMS to your stored procedure node under programmability.  Click View-Object Explorer Details and a count of objects will be displayed on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the query you can use:

```
 select count(*) from sysobjects where xtype='P'
```

If all your db access is mandated to be through SP's, then the sky is the limit.

Answer (score 1):

This will exclude the ones that sometimes get created when using the diagramming tool (they will start with dt_)

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.routines
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(SPECIFIC_NAME),'IsMSShipped') =1
AND  routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use them, then there really is no such thing as "too many".

I had a developer concerned his stored procs were using too much space in the database, so I had to actually calculate the total SIZE of all stored procs. [Good answer for that here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219570/how-do-i-calculate-the-size-of-stored-procedures-in-sql-server-2005) The upshot was that the size of the stored procs together was responsible for maybe .001% of the total size of the database.

Comment: >>I had a developer concerned his stored procs were using too much space in the database, so I had to actually calculate the total SIZE of all stored procs.

That's insane.  Hopefully you enjoy silly challenges ;)

Comment: That's why I love StackOverflow!
Actually, the request was more like "please provide a complete breakdown of space usage in database [x], including tables, indexes, and stored procedures". Tables and indexes is easy. Actual size of stored procs is a little harder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple query you can use:

```
SELECT COUNT(object_id) FROM sys.procedures
```

Answer (score 0):

With this query, you'll get the data amount of the actual text in all the procs in the DB.
The results is in bytes, so do the math for a MB results (1024*1024).
divide it by 1048576

```
SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(sm.definition))/1048576 as 'Total Proc text size'
FROM sys.sql_modules sm
INNER JOIN sys.sysobjects so ON sm.object_id = so.id
WHERE so.type = 'P'
```