# Counting lines of code of Stored Procedures in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, code-metrics

Using SQL Server 2005 management studio, I have exported each Sprocs and Functions as a separate .sql file.

Is there a way that using CLOC tool, I can produce lines of code metric?

The CLOC site states that it supports SQL but it does not generate any metric in this case.

Thanks,

Ajit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a tool that satisfies my requirement:

http://www.downloadthat.com/windows/Programming/Misc-Tools/OxyProject-Metrics_download.html

If anything better, pl share it.

Thanks.

Ajit.

Answer (score 0):

Might this be of help: [How do I calculate the SIZE of stored procedures in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219570/how-do-i-calculate-the-size-of-stored-procedures-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0):

WHy don't you use "Generate Scripts" by rightlciking on your database in Management studio, selecting your tables/stored procs/functions, and then exporting it to one giant file.
From that, you can use a tool like notepad++ (or even notepad if u take word wrap off and status bar on), to see number of lines.
or you can use CLOC on this one file created. Which ever makes you happy.

Comment: There are 2000+ procedures currently. I am looking for targeting specific procedures for refactoring.